# Missing filter function on excel version 1908

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The excel my work uses doesn't support the filter function so I'm trying to figure out a way to replace the way I used the filter function from this graph. The green is the original raw data, the orange is how I'd like to separate the data, and the blue is my desired final product.

Is there a good replacement for the filter function?

[image]

Comment: `SUMIFS` maybe? Some sample data and the expected result is needed here.

Comment: @BigBen I just added pictures to help explain what I mean... I used sumifs but I need to find out a way to filter the data without using the filter function.

Comment: What's the logic to get from the green table to the orange table?

Comment: @BigBen There's no logic... the orange table is just how I would like the data in the green table to be sorted out to get the blue table.

Comment: Where is the formula you used?  And why do you need to filter the data more than what SUMIFS can do?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Heres a formula I used: "=SUM(SUMIF($A$2:$A$14, FILTER(Product[Letter], Product[Group] = 'Line 1'!A23), $B$2:$B$14))" I need to filter the letters by groups so I used both SUMIF and filter but my work excel doesn't support the filter function so I'm looking for a replacement.

Comment: I don't understand how that formula relates to the sample data you have shown. Different columns; ranges; etc. To reproduce and help with your issue, it would be helpful for you to provide a formula that works on your given data samples.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld sorry about unclarity. I updated the picture and included the formula I'm currently using. How would you recommend getting the same outcome without using the filter function? Thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: Much easier to sort this out with your current examples.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula to avoid `FILTER`

```
C13:  =SUM(SUMIF($B$3:$B$10,INDEX($F:$F,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($G$4:$G$11=B13)*ROW($G$4:$G$11),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNT(1/($G$4:$G$11=B13)*ROW($G$4:$G$11)))))),$C$3:$C$10))
```

[image]

To directly answer your question, a substitute for the `FILTER` function, given your layout of data, would be:

```
=INDEX($F:$F,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($G$4:$G$11=B13)*ROW($G$4:$G$11),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNT(1/($G$4:$G$11=B13)*ROW($G$4:$G$11))))))
```

and with Tables and Structured References:

```
=INDEX(Table9[ID],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(Table9[Group]=B13)*ROW(Table9)-ROW(Table9[#Headers]),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNT(1/(Table9[Group]=B13)*ROW(Table9)-ROW(Table9[#Headers]))))))
```

The filter substitutes should work on any version of Excel that has the `AGGREGATE` function which, I believe, appeared with Excel 2007.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!